# Generic Class for return enumerated results based on Electrical Engineering formula input and condition criteria c#

Tags: c#

I work on a program that needs to do engineering formula checking/validation.
Very similar to Unit Testing but I need something very generic so I don't have to make a ton of classes.

**I need to pass an input formula:**
Example: x = input voltage, y = voltage reference to find decibel.
Equation is 20*log10(x/y)

**And validate the result for the use-case application**

Examples:
If Application can't exceed 60 decibels and value is 72 then result is fail.

I have so many of these to do that it would be nice to have one generic class, pass in the input formula in as a Func<>, then have a Dictionary<[criteria],Enum.ResultType]> (or something) that will return the results for that application.

Here's what I was thinking/needing:

**Non-working code, just to illustrate concept**

```
public enum CiteriaCheckResult
    {
        Inconclusive,
        Fail,
        Warning,
        Pass
    }

//T is the return type of the specific engineering formula
public class CriteriaCheck<T> 
        {
            public Dictionary<?, CiteriaCheckResult> Criteria { get; set; } = new Dictionary<?, CiteriaCheckResult>();

            //T1 and T2 are the inputs for a specific engineering formula
            //T is the output value to test against the criteria conditions
            public CiteriaCheckResult Validate<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, T> input)
            {
                //nested if's?
                //switch case?
                //Criteria.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == input result == criteria)?

                return CiteriaCheckResult base on dictionary or other user configurable criteria type;
            }
        }
```

**Desired Usage:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test1 = new CriteriaCheck<double>();
            //add criteria for specific application
            Criteria.Add("criteria to check against input result", CiteriaCheckResult.Inconclusive);
            Criteria.Add("value is < [] && value is > []", CiteriaCheckResult.Fail);
            Criteria.Add("value is <= Room.Value", CiteriaCheckResult.Pass);
            Criteria.Add("if value is > -6", CiteriaCheckResult.Warning);

            double x = 1.23;
            double y = .7549;

            //run func and return enum based on user set conditions
            Console.WriteLine($"Test 1: {test1.Validate<double, double>((x,y) => 20 * Math.Log10(x/y))}");



            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

There are obviously a lot of problems with what I'm showing (like not having unique values for dictionary keys) but hopefully the intent of what I'm trying to accomplish is clear and ya'll can think of a clever way to do this.

Comment: I found out the requirements for this have changed... thanks again for those who spent time and posted solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the time and effort guys.
I found out this morning that the requirements have changed including validation messages why the criteria failed need to be displayed on the GUI.

So I'm just going to make a base class implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo and make a class for each validation type. will be a lot of more classes but a generic class won't handle all the new requirements.

**Example Usage**

```
public class EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck : CriteriaCheckItemBase
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            //set description
            CheckProperty = "Check Equipment Enclosure Size";

            //set validation rules
            AddValidationRule<EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck, double>(CiteriaCheckResult.Fail, "Equipment is too tall for the Enclosure", t => t.EquipmentRUHeight > t.EnclosureRUHeight);
            AddValidationRule<EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck, double>(CiteriaCheckResult.Warning, "Enclosure is taller than the Equipment", t => t.EquipmentRUHeight < t.EnclosureRUHeight);
            AddValidationRule<EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck, double>(CiteriaCheckResult.Pass, "Equipment height fits in the Enclosure", t => t.EquipmentRUHeight == t.EnclosureRUHeight);

            AddValidationRule<EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck, double>(CiteriaCheckResult.Fail, "Equipment is too wide for the Enclosure", t => t.EquipmentRUWidth > t.EnclosureRUWidth);
            AddValidationRule<EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck, double>(CiteriaCheckResult.Warning, "Enclosure is wider than the Equipment", t => t.EquipmentRUWidth < t.EnclosureRUWidth);
            AddValidationRule<EquipmentRackSizeCriteriaCheck, double>(CiteriaCheckResult.Pass, "Equipment width fits in the Enclosure", t => t.EquipmentRUWidth == t.EnclosureRUWidth);

            //initialize complete
            base.Initialize();
        }

        public int EquipmentRUHeight { get; set; }
        public int EquipmentRUWidth { get; set; }
        public int EnclosureRUHeight { get; set; }
        public int EnclosureRUWidth { get; set; }
    }
```

**Base Class**

```
public class CriteriaCheckItemBase : INotifyDataErrorInfo, ISupportInitializeNotification
    {
        private Dictionary<CiteriaCheckResultType, Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>> _validationDictionary = new Dictionary<CiteriaCheckResultType, Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>>();

        public CriteriaCheckItemBase()
        {
            //intialize object
            BeginInit();
        }

        public virtual void Initialize()
        {
            //set description
            //CheckProperty = "";

            //set validation rules

            //initialize complete
            EndInit();
        }

        public string CheckProperty { get; set; }

        public CiteriaCheckResultType CheckResult { get; set; }

        public string CheckMessage { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<CriteriaCheckResult> ResultsCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CriteriaCheckResult>();

        public void AddValidationRule<T1, T2>(CiteriaCheckResultType checkResult, string message, Expression<Func<T1, bool>> rule) where T1 : CriteriaCheckItemBase
        {
            if (!_validationDictionary.ContainsKey(checkResult))
            {
                _validationDictionary.TryAdd(checkResult, new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>());
            }

            if (_validationDictionary.TryGetValue(checkResult, out Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> rules))
            {
                rules.TryAdd(message ?? "No Message for this Result", rule);
            }
        }

        #region INotifyDataErrorInfo

        public bool HasErrors => (GetErrors("") is Dictionary<CiteriaCheckResultType, List<string>> c) ? c.Count > 0 : false;

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            var results = _validationDictionary.OrderBy(o => (int)o.Key).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.Where(c => (bool)c.Value.Compile().DynamicInvoke(this)).Select(s => s.Key).ToList());

            ResultsCollection.Clear();

            foreach (CiteriaCheckResultType resultType in results.Keys)
            {
                foreach (string msg in results[resultType])
                {
                    ResultsCollection.Add(new CriteriaCheckResult() { CheckResult = resultType, CheckMessage = msg });
                }
            }

            return ResultsCollection;
        }

        #endregion


        #region ISupportInitializeNotification

        public event EventHandler Initialized;

        private bool _isInitialized;
        public bool IsInitialized
        {
            get { return _isInitialized; }
            private set
            {
                _isInitialized = value;
                if (_isInitialized) { RaiseInitialized(); }
            }
        }

        public void BeginInit()
        {
            if (IsInitialized) { IsInitialized = false; }
            else { Initialize(); }
        }

        public void EndInit()
        {
            IsInitialized = true;
        }

        #endregion

        protected void RaiseInitialized()
        {
            this.Initialized?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        public void RaisErrorChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var checker = new CriteriaCheck<double>
        {
            FailValidator = (input => input < 0)
        };
        var result = checker.Validate((x, y) => x * y, 1.2, 0.7);
    }
}

public enum CiteriaCheckResult
{
    Inconclusive,
    Fail,
    Warning,
    Pass
}

public class CriteriaCheck<T>
{
    public Func<T, bool> InconclusiveValidator { get; set; } = p => false;
    public Func<T, bool> FailValidator { get; set; } = p => false;
    public Func<T, bool> WarningValidator { get; set; } = p => false;

    public CiteriaCheckResult Validate<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, T> input, T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        if (InconclusiveValidator(input(t1, t2)))
            return CiteriaCheckResult.Inconclusive;
        else if (FailValidator(input(t1, t2)))
            return CiteriaCheckResult.Fail;
        else if (WarningValidator(input(t1, t2)))
            return CiteriaCheckResult.Warning;
        else
            return CiteriaCheckResult.Pass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution. I tried to add comments to make it self-explanatory.

```
public enum CiteriaCheckResult
{
    Inconclusive,
    Fail,
    Warning,
    Pass
}

//T is the return type of the specific engineering formula
public class CriteriaCheck<T>
{
    public Dictionary<Type, object[]> Criteria = new Dictionary<Type, object[]>();

    //T1 and T2 are the inputs for a specific engineering formula
    //T is the output value to test against the criteria conditions
    public CiteriaCheckResult Validate<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, T> input, T1 x, T2 y)
    {
        if(Criteria.Keys.Contains(input.GetType()))
        {
            // Calculate/Run the Func the value from incoming parameters
            T result = input(x, y);
            object[] m1 = Criteria[input.GetType()];

            // Calculate/Run the Func existing in the Array
            T m2 = (m1[0] as Func<T1, T2, T>)(x, y);
            if(result.Equals(m2))
            {
               // If the values match then:
                return (CiteriaCheckResult)m1[1];
            }
        }
        return CiteriaCheckResult.Inconclusive;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<decimal, decimal, int> n1 = (x,y) => 1;
        Func<int, int> n2 = (x) => 5;
        Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> n3 = (x, y) => 3;

        CriteriaCheck<decimal> test = new CriteriaCheck<decimal>();

        object[] obj0 = { n1, CiteriaCheckResult.Fail };
        test.Criteria.Add(n1.GetType(), obj0);

        object[] obj1 = { n2, CiteriaCheckResult.Inconclusive };
        test.Criteria.Add(n2.GetType(), obj1);

        object[] obj2 = { n3, CiteriaCheckResult.Pass };
        test.Criteria.Add(n3.GetType(), obj2);

        var result = test.Validate(n3, 1, 2);
    }
}
```